# Entity not spawning after being summoned Java

Tags: java, eclipse, entity

So I am trying to call an entity called Mothership with a texture. What should be happening is that the image appears where the player is (temporary place till it appears). Instead, no matter where I move it, it does not appear.

This dropbox link is to the whole game because it all links together.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kuvoxzjf00wa8jf/AAD-MaXXcnHMn4PtW-X_vHcUa?dl=0

I thought maybe it's because of Controller.java, not initialising it but I was getting errors. In the end, I want the mothership to be stationary and appear on the side that the player spawns on. The mothership will lose health from enemy bullets which I am working on at the moment.

But here are the bits that I have been focussing my attention to:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(tex.nmothership, (int) x, (int) y, null);

    }
```

^This is in Mothership.java

```
public void init(){
            requestFocus();
            BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
            try {
                spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/spriteSheet.png");
                background = loader.loadImage("/background.png");
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            tex = new Textures(this);
            c = new Controller(tex, this);
            p = new Player(200, 200, tex, this, c);
            menu = new Menu();
            mothership = new Mothership(200, 200, tex); 

            ea = c.getEntityA();
            eb = c.getEntityB();

            this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this));
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
            c.createEnemy(enemy_count);
                //e = error

         }
```

^In Game.java (the main engine of the game)

```
private void getTextures() {
        player = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
        missile = ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
        enemy = ss.grabImage(3, 1, 32, 32);
        emissile = ss.grabImage(4, 1, 32, 32);
        nmothership = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 128, 128);
```

^In Textures.java - the grabImage is from Spritesheet.java

Comment: I will try again today to work it out. This is the same program as the last question but a different mechanic. If anyone can respond with something it would be highly appreciative because my game is due this Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I managed to get the "mothership" to spawn however it has come at the price of commenting out the mothership's physics mechanic. I will make another post about it if I am still having trouble.

Comment: Here is the code for the physics mechanic in the Mothership                             class.public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < game.eb.size(); i++)
        {
            EntityB tempEnt = game.eb.get(i);

            if(Physics.Collision((EntityA) this, tempEnt)){
               c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
               Game.MHEALTH -= 20;
            }
       }   

    }